# Appending Buttons to Input-Fields via Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm currently working with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and have a problem concerning the size of elements. I'd like to create an input field with an appended button. That's why I'm using a div with "input-append", which sorrounds the input and the button tag.
Now my problem: I want everything to be a bit bigger. So i gave the button tag the property "btn-large". Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a similar property for the input field.
How can I fit the input field to the appended button?

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span3" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text"><button class="btn btn-large" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Heres an impression of my problem:

[image]

Regards,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following style and if you want bigger then increase padding.

```
input, button{ 
    padding: 7px;    
}
```

Comment: I did it like this:
    input[type="text"]{
        padding:9px;
    }

Now it fits to the button (the button is also defined as padding 9px). Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Define **box-sizing** to your `input field`. Write like this:

```
input, button{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: The standard one should be in last position

Comment: Cool idea, but I changed the padding - was quite simpler. Thank you anyway!